How to apply "outer" on data frames in Tidyverse?
I have a data frame that contains measurements for multiple groups. I want to apply outer to each pair of groups and compute a summary. Can it be done in Tidyverse style? Below is an example of how to do it with two loops. I have played around with expand_grid and group_by, but without success.
df <- iris
groups = as.character(levels(df$Species))
n <- length(groups)
out <- matrix(numeric(n*n), nrow = n, ncol = n)
colnames(out) <- groups
rownames(out) <- groups
for (sp1 in 1:n) {
  for (sp2 in 1:n) {
    out[sp1, sp2] <- sum(outer(
      unlist(subset(df, Species == groups[sp1], Sepal.Length)),
      unlist(subset(df, Species == groups[sp2], Sepal.Length)),
      ">"))
  }
}
out

           setosa versicolor virginica
setosa       1128        139        34
versicolor   2302       1169       479
virginica    2457       1927      1165


Whatever you want to do can certainly be done in the tridyverse, but there may be better ways than using outer, which is not part of the tidyverse.  What meaning do the numbers in your desired output represent?  That would help us with the translation...  and, imho, "if I'm thinking of using a for loop, there's probably a better way to do it in R" is good rule of thumb.

It does not have to use 'outer'. The example computes a summary function (sum) of the output of a binary function (greater than) on all pairs of observations grouped by a factor. How would you do it in tidyverse?

I can't answer that until I know what you're trying to do.  Your comment suggests that you want the sum of x~in~ for x~in~ > x~jm~ for all pairswise combinations of (i, j) in (setosa, versicolor, virginica).  Is that correct?  If so, what do you do when the number of elements differes between your lists i and j.

The pairwise combinations produce an n times m matrix. Why would it matter if n != m? I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

1) Base R With these sorts of calculations base R is probably more appropriate. We can split Sepal.Length into a 3 element list s, one component per Species, and then use outer or a double sapply.
s <- with(iris, split(Sepal.Length, Species))
outer(s, s, Vectorize(\(x, y) sum(outer(y, x, "<"))))

##            setosa versicolor virginica
## setosa       1128        139        34
## versicolor   2302       1169       479
## virginica    2457       1927      1165

# alternately replace the line with outer with this
sapply(s, \(u) sapply(s, \(v) sum(outer(u, v, "<"))))

2) magrittr We could make this into a magrittr pipeline like this:
library(magrittr)
iris %>%
  with(split(Sepal.Length, Species)) %>%
  outer(., ., Vectorize(\(x, y) sum(outer(y, x, "<"))))

3) tidyverse or to go full tidyverse
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>%
  select(Sepal.Length, Species) %>%
  expand_grid(a = ., b = .) %>%
  unnest(c(a, b), names_sep = ".") %>%
  summarize(value = sum(a.Sepal.Length < b.Sepal.Length), 
            .by = ends_with("Species")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = b.Species, names_from = a.Species) %>%
  rename(Species = b.Species)

##   # A tibble: 3 × 4
##   Species    setosa versicolor virginica
##   <fct>       <int>      <int>     <int>
## 1 setosa       1128        139        34
## 2 versicolor   2302       1169       479
## 3 virginica    2457       1927      1165

4) tapply Another base R approach is via tapply like this:
with(iris, tapply(kronecker(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Length, "<"), 
  expand.grid(Species = Species, Species = Species), sum))
##             Species
## Species      setosa versicolor virginica
##   setosa       1128        139        34
##   versicolor   2302       1169       479
##   virginica    2457       1927      1165


Clearly this is not a case for Tidyverse, but thank you for the examples.
